# Difference between np.matmul und PEP 465

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-465

Does that mean, that if I import numpy @ is equivalent to np.matmul()?

Comment: Dupe is a bit of a different question, but the first line of the top answer: "The @ operator calls the array's __matmul__ method, not dot. This method is also present in the API as the function np.matmul."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. As you can read in the [`np.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) documentation:

> **Notes**
>
> The matmul function implements the semantics of the @ operator introduced in Python 3.5 following PEP465.